# Reading first N characters of a PDF file using PDFBox

Tags: java, file-io, pdfbox

I wrote the following function that jut prints out the text in a PDF using PDFBox tool:

```
private String readFirstNChars(int N) { // N has not been used
    PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = null;
    PDDocument pdDocument = null;
    COSDocument cosDocument = null;
    File currentFile = this.pdfFile;

    try {
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(currentFile));
        parser.parse();
        cosDocument = parser.getDocument();
        pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDocument = new PDDocument(cosDocument);
        pdfTextStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfTextStripper.setEndPage(1);
        String parsedText = pdfTextStripper.getText(pdDocument);
        return parsedText;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I was thinking of printing first `N` characters of `parsedText` but then I wondered if the file that I could read was very big in size, this method would not make any sense i.e. load the whole text in memory and then get first `N` characters. Is there a way I can read only `N` characters from a PDF?

Comment: PDF isn't HTML. PDFBox reads the whole PDF to parse it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr is right, PDFBox first reads the whole PDF into memory which is more (probably considerably so) than the text to extract. But still you can prevent your code to do unnecessary work, e.g. by only reading the text from the first page. `PDFTextStripper` has methods to restrict text extraction to a page range.

Comment: I was thinking about reading only the first page but wasn't sure. Thanks for assuring.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need source code of the PDFParser so you can write the appropriate method or write your own. PDF is more than just the readable text, so essentially you need to parse the document, discarding the non-readable text and then keeping a count of the actual text you find.